# How to split and display distinct letters from a word in SQL?

Tags: sql

Yesterday in a job interview session I was asked this question and I had no clue about it. Suppose I  have a word "Manhattan " I want to display only the letters 'M','A','N','H','T'
in SQL. How to do it?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'd probably write a stored proc to do this, but only if I HAD to use SQL. Otherwise, I'd use an actual programming language.

Comment: Actual programming languages make this job simpler . But how to do it in SQL ? Please show me through.

Comment: For *which* SQL implementation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, here is my solution ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/34733)) - it aims to use a "Relational SQL" operations, which *may* have been what the interviewer was going for conceptually.

Most of the work done is simply to turn the string into a set of (pos, letter) records as the relevant final applied [DQL](http://www.takveen.com/z-art_comp_ora_sql_ch1_p3.html) is a mere SELECT with a grouping and ordering applied.

```
select letter
from (
  -- All of this just to get a set of (pos, letter)
  select ns.n as pos, substring(ss.s, ns.n, 1) as letter
  from (select 'MANHATTAN' as s) as ss
  cross join (
    -- Or use another form to create a "numbers table"
    select n from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) as X(n)
    ) as ns
  ) as pairs
group by letter    -- guarantees distinctness
order by min(pos)  -- ensure output is ordered MANHT
```

The above query works in SQL Server 2008, but the ["Numbers Table"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable) may have to be altered for other vendors. Otherwise, there is nothing used that is vendor specific - no CTE, or cross application of a function, or procedural language code ..

That being said, the above is to show a conceptual approach - SQL is designed for use with sets and relations and multiplicity across records; the above example is, in some sense, merely a perversion of such.

---

Examining the intermediate relation,

```
  select ns.n as pos, substring(ss.s, ns.n, 1) as letter
  from (select 'MANHATTAN' as s) as ss
  cross join (
    select n from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) as X(n)
    ) as ns
```

uses a [cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) to generate the Cartesian product of the string (1 row) with the numbers (9 rows); the `substring` function is then applied with the string and *each* number to obtain each character in accordance with its position. The resulting set contains the records-

```
POS LETTER
1   M
2   A
3   N
..
9   N
```

Then the outer select groups each record according to the letter and the resulting records  are ordered by the minimum (first) occurrence position of the letter that establishing the grouping. (Without the order by the letters would have been distinct but the final order would not be guaranteed.)

Comment: Please pardon my intellect ... can you just explain the steps please?
A little more

Comment: @user3655102 I've added a bit more explanation - hope it clears things up.

Comment: I am wondering why you skipped the `(7)`, and I guess solution is for 9 characters long word only.

Comment: @sallushan Whoops, skipping 7 was a mistake. It's a good thing the `T` was a duplicate, so the result is the same! (I've updated the post to add in 7.)

Comment: @sallushan In this case I hardcoded 1..9, but with a full "numbers table" or derived relation would have *many* numbers so the usage would look more like: `.. from (select 'MANHATTAN' as s) as ss cross join numbers ns where ns.n >=1 and ns.n <= LEN(..)`. In addition to the link in the post, see ["Creative Solutions by Using a Number Table"](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/creative-solutions-by-using-a-number-table/) which talks about creating and using a "numbers table".

Answer (score 7):

One way (if using SQL Server) is with a [recursive CTE (Commom Table Expression)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

```
DECLARE @source nvarchar(100) = 'MANHATTAN'
;
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@source, 1, 1) AS c1, 1 as Pos
    WHERE LEN(@source) > 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@source, Pos + 1, 1) AS c1, Pos + 1 as Pos
    FROM cte
    WHERE Pos < LEN(@source)
)
SELECT DISTINCT c1 from cte
```

[SqlFiddle for this is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/34747). I had to inline the `@source` for SqlFiddle, but the code above works fine in Sql Server.

The first `SELECT` generates the initial row(in this case 'M', 1). The second `SELECT` is the recursive part that generates the subsequent rows, with the `Pos` column getting incremented each time until the termination condition `WHERE Pos < LEN(@source)` is finally met. The final select removes the duplicates. Internally, `SELECT DISTINCT` sorts the rows in order to facilitate the removal of duplicates, which is why the final output happens to be in alphabetic order. Since you didn't specify order as a requirement, I left it as-is. But you could modify it to use a `GROUP` instead, that ordered on `MIN(Pos)` if you needed the output in the characters' original order.

This same technique can be used for things like generating all the Bigrams for a string, with just a small change to the general structure above.

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @charr varchar(99)
declare @lp int
set @charr='Manhattan'
set @lp=1

DECLARE @T1 TABLE (
FLD VARCHAR(max)
)

while(@lp<=LEN(@charr))
begin
    if(not exists(select * from @T1 where FLD=(select SUBSTRING(@charr,@lp,1))))
    begin
        insert into @T1
        select SUBSTRING(@charr,@lp,1)
    end
    set @lp=@lp+1

end

select * from @T1
```

check this it may help u

Comment: Yes but will it select distinct ones? i.e. A would come 2 times T would come twice also . right?

Comment: i have modified my answer chk now

Comment: Make sure to specify which SQL implementation(s) this works in.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an Oracle version of **@user2864740**'s answer. The only difference is how you construct the "*numbers table*" (plus slight differences in aliasing)

```
select letter
from (
  select ns.n as pos, substr(ss.s, ns.n, 1) as letter
  from (select 'MANHATTAN' as s from dual)  ss
  cross join  (
   SELECT  LEVEL as n
   FROM DUAL
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9
   ORDER BY LEVEL)  ns
) pairs
group by letter    
order by min(pos)
```